# Selection Algorithm in Rank Trees

Tags: c++, select, binary-search-tree

I'm looking to write an algorithm that given an index k, finds the k-th smallest number (call it x) in the tree, and returns the sum of all the bigger numbers than x.

Let's say I have a rank tree of 5 nodes , Select(2) should return the sum of the biggest 3 nodes in the tree.

I have this code in C++ , but I think I'm getting inaccurate results in some cases , I can't work it out to find whats wrong with my algorithm. I added two new fields in every node of my tree, where each node holds the size of its' sub-tree (field : W) and the sum of all the nodes in its' sub-tree (field: sub).

Here's the code:

```
template<class K, class D>
typename AVL<K, D>::tree_node* AVL<K, D>::Select(tree_node* p, int r,
    int *sum) {
 if (!p)
    return NULL;
 if (r == 0) {
    *sum += p->getSub();
    return p;
  }
 if (p->left) {
    if (p->left->getW() == r - 1) {
        *sum = *sum + p->getSub() - p->left->getSub() - p->Key();
        return p;
    }
    if (p->left->getW() > r - 1) {
        *sum = *sum + p->getSub() - p->left->getSub();
        return Select(p->left, r, sum);
    }

    return Select(p->right, r - p->left->getW() - 1, sum);
 }

return Select(p->right, r - 1, sum);
```

}

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is to add iterator-like analogs of begin(), end(), and operator++ for iterators (pretty easy to implement). And then you start from begin(), use operator ++ k times, and then iterate rest of the tree using operator++ calculating sum of iterated objects

Comment: But that would be O(n) complexity, unlike the Select algorithm which is O(logn). Plus, I added the node fields so I wont have to iterate through the whole tree but instead only through the search path for x

Comment: Any help please?